# Except operation in TSQL returning error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to apply an `EXCEPT` (same as `MINUS` in Oracle) operation in TSQL. I tried with a simple code

```
select * from Table1
except
select * from Table1 where calndr_dt between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-10'`
```

Each sub query is executing fine. But when joined with `EXCEPT`, it is returning the following error message.

> Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'except'.

Comment: I assume your actual query is more complex because surely this could be done by just running the second query and bracketing the `WHERE` clause with `NOT ()`?

Comment: It doesn't say "Incorrect syntax near *the keyword* 'except'."? What version are you on? If <2005 it is not available.

Comment: I am using 2012 version.

Comment: Yes the actual query is much more complex. There also I got the same error. That is why I thought of experimenting with a simple piece of code.

Comment: It works on SQLFiddle, so I'm not sure where the error could be? Could you post the whole code? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcf8f/1

Comment: You could have some incorrect line endings maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738253/incorrect-syntax-near-go-in-sql-server-management-studio

Comment: @NickyvV this is the actual code used for the experiment.

select * from calndr_dimn
except
select * from calndr_dimn where calndr_dt between '2014-10-01' and '2014-10-10'

Comment: Please execute `SELECT @@VERSION` and tell us the results.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 10.0.4830.1 (X64) Aug 27 2014 18:15:02 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Parallel Data Warehouse (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: )

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ORDER BY clause from the first query, if you have this clause.

Comment: No. I am not using any ORDER BY clause.