# Getting error in SQL Server "Incorrect syntax near "GO" " when I copy page script from notepad but not when I write"GO"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Getting error in SQL Server

> Incorrect syntax near "GO"

when I copy page script from notepad.

But if I write "GO" instead of copy paste in SQL Server Management Studio then I don't get that error

[image]

[image]

**Notepad file:**
[download file](http://wikisend.com/download/962642/go_test.txt)

Comment: If you delete between `Northwind` and `GO` then hit enter and run again, does it work?  If you copy the working query from SSMS to notepad then back again, does it work?

Comment: If I remove first GO (line # 2) then same error. If I remove second GO (line # 4) then it works. I guess there is some kind of encoding problem

Comment: I've seen such things in imported files before, but never in copied queries, but you can change the encoding of your notepad file, or use a different text editor altogether.

Comment: I coped four lines into notepad file and saved and closed.Then I opened it and copied pasted to sqlserver management studio. Same error. I am going to attach notepad file here (that I tested). Someone give me script file which have more then 10,000 rows. So I don't want to replace go or something like that

Comment: *someone give me notepad file(txt file) of queries (not database script file)

Comment: I have changed encoding of notepad file but still not working.

Comment: I bet if you opened this in a hex editor you'd see there is some hidden character on the line.

Comment: What if you manually type the lines into a new blank file in Notepad, and then copy them to SSMS and execute them?

Comment: I get same error message from your file (even if I replace Northwind with one of my own databases). In hex edit, the only difference I can see is the first statement has a CrLf before `GO` while the second has a Cr. This cannot cause the failure, and replacing the Cr with CrLf still causes the error. Flabbergasted

Answer (score 0):

As I said in a comment: the only difference is a Cr vs CrLf. I didn't expect it to make a difference, nor have I ever seen it make a difference. Queries with Cr or Lf or CrLf have always worked perfectly fine for me. However, apparently, the sql parser sometimes does have a problem with Cr. (Based on the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738253/incorrect-syntax-near-go-in-sql-server-management-studio)).
So I guess a replace is what you need to do, unpleasant as it is.